# É uma boa ideia mapear URLs que deletam entradas em GET?

Tags: python, http, url, django

Estou estudando Django e me perguntei se é realmente uma boa prática configurar URL's de remoções via GET, por exemplo: `http://meusite.com.br/usuario/deletar?id=10`.

Essa é realmente uma boa prática? Tendo em vista que alguma biblioteca de acesso HTTP pode, de repente, ser utilizada para fazer um loop e apagar várias entradas baseado nesse modelo de URL.

Sei que existem os cookies para registrar guardar os dados da sessão e que talvez é imprudente permitir a deleção leviana de itens sem nenhum controle, mas não sei como fazer isso.

O Django provê alguma proteção quanto a esse modelo de mapeamento? Caso seja uma má ideia mapear dessa maneira, qual uma boa prática para fazer uma remoção de objetos mais segura?

Comment: Para deletar algo use o método HTTP `DELETE`, ou, no máximo, um `POST`. Mas nunca um `GET`. Seja como for isso não afeta segurança e nunca impede automação. Se quer segurança então deve autenticar usuários e restringir quem pode executar a operação de deletar (seja como for que ela chegue ao servidor).

Comment: Não vejo problema em usar `GET`, não é aí que a segurança deve estar.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal entendi.

Comment: @bfavaretto o único problema de uma operação destrutiva em um GET seria que um crawler pode abrir "sem querer". Mas seja como for, uma segurança correta vai evitar isso.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/49322/quais-as-vantagens-de-se-utilizar-os-m%C3%A9todos-http-corretos

Comment: Já me contaram a história de um caso onde uma equipe achava que seus servidores estavam sendo invadidos mas era só um buscador "indexando" os /deletar (e conseqüentemente apagando tudo que encontrava!).  

Se algum tutorial usou esse exemplo, seria bom enviar um bug report, não se deve ensinar uma coisa dessas!

Comment: @marcus Muito bom. Gostei tanto do seu comentário, que tomei a liberdade de editar a minha resposta apenas para citá-lo. :)

Comment: Valeu! Sempre lembro dessa história quando ouço falar de GET × POST. Vi que essa possibilidade já tinha sido levantada, então só deixei um comentário para reforçar a ideia.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Isso é uma má ideia

O GET deve ser seguro, [tal como especificado pela W3C na RFC 2616](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) (dê uma olhada no capítulo 9):

> 9.1.1 Safe Methods
>
> Implementors should be aware that the software represents the user in
>     their interactions over the Internet, and should be careful to allow
>     the user to be aware of any actions they might take which may have an
>     unexpected significance to themselves or others.
>
> In particular, the convention has been established that the GET and
>     HEAD methods SHOULD NOT have the significance of taking an action
>     other than retrieval. These methods ought to be considered "safe".
>     This allows user agents to represent other methods, such as POST, PUT
>     and DELETE, in a special way, so that the user is made aware of the
>     fact that a possibly unsafe action is being requested.
>
> Naturally, it is not possible to ensure that the server does not
>     generate side-effects as a result of performing a GET request; in
>     fact, some dynamic resources consider that a feature. The important
>     distinction here is that the user did not request the side-effects,
>     so therefore cannot be held accountable for them.

Traduzindo para o português (minha tradução):

> 9.1.1 Métodos seguros
>
> Implementadores devem saber que o software representa o usuário em suas interações na Internet, e devem ser cuidadosos em deixar que o usuário perceba quaisquer ações que eles realizem que possam ter um significado inesperado para si ou para outros.
>
> Em particular, a convenção que foi estabelecida é que os métodos GET e HEAD NÃO DEVEM ter outra ação de significância além de obtenção. Estes métodos serão considerados "seguros". Isto permite que agentes do usuário possam representar outros métodos, tais como POST, PUT e DELETE, de uma forma especial, para que então os usuários percebam o fato de que uma ação possivelmente insegura está sendo solicitada.
>
> Naturalmente, não é possível assegurar-se que o servidor não gerará efeitos colaterais como resultado da execução da requisição GET; de fato, alguns recursos dinâmicos consideram isso uma funcionalidade. A distinção importante aqui é que o usuário não solicitou os efeitos colaterais, e portanto não pode ser responsabilizado por eles.

Vamos enfatizar o segundo parágrafo. Um método GET (ou HEAD) não deve significar outra coisa além da obtenção de um recurso. Isto claramente vai contra a ideia de ter uma requisição GET que exclua um usuário. Além disso, tal como falado no terceiro parágrafo, quando o usuário executa um GET (normalmente através do navegador), ele não espera que essa ação tenha efeitos colaterais*, ainda mais um efeito colateral tal como deletar um usuário.

(*) Alguns efeitos colaterais simples, tal como aumentar o contador de visitas, estão ok, desde que sejam inofensivos. O mesmo vale para questões internas do servidor que são invisíveis ao usuário, tal como cache e logging.

Ah sim, e antes que alguém pergunte, o "seguro" neste contexto refere-se ao sentido de "a ação não causar nenhum efeito possivelmente danoso" (tal como a criação, alteração ou exclusão de recursos). Isso não significa ser seguro no sentido de evitar vazamento de informações ou de evitar o acesso indevido a recursos, isso já é outra coisa.

#### Quais são os potenciais riscos?

Essa URL poderia ser compartilhada aonde não deveria. Por exemplo, eu poderia enviá-la por e-mail ou postar em algum lugar qualquer na internet como aqui no StackOverflow com a finalidade de ludibriar o usuário e induzí-lo a fazer algo que não era o que ele queria, tal como no link abaixo (observe a URL do link):

> [Clique aqui para ver as fotos da festa!](http://meusite.com.br/usuario/deletar?id=10)

O resultado disso é óbvio. Ao clicar na URL, o usuário acaba por realizar uma ação que não pretendia realizar. A navegação normal do usuário pelo site não deveria causar efeitos colaterais indesejados.

Além dissso, esta URL pode acabar por ser encontrada por robôs de busca que poderão tentar navegar por ela (o exemplo mais óbvio é o Google). O [marcus](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/2452/marcus) deu um exemplo anedótico [neste comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/49312/%c3%89-uma-boa-ideia-mapear-urls-que-deletam-entradas-em-get/49319#comment99922_49312) demonstrando o perigo que isso representa:

> Já me contaram a história de um caso onde uma equipe achava que seus servidores estavam sendo invadidos mas era só um buscador "indexando" os /deletar (e conseqüentemente apagando tudo que encontrava!). Se algum tutorial usou esse exemplo, seria bom enviar um bug report, não se deve ensinar uma coisa dessas!

#### Como proceder?

Utilizar o método GET não é a forma correta. O ideal é usar o método DELETE que serve exatamente para esta finalidade (destruir, invalidar ou apagar um recurso web). Entretanto em alguns casos, você pode ficar limitado somente a usar POST ou GET, e neste caso a solução é óbvia (por eliminação): utilize o POST.

Quanto as questões de segurança (no sentido de evitar acessos indevidos), vale utilizar HTTPS se pertinente e adotar medidas de proteção contra [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery), [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) e outros possíveis problemas. Para isso vale verificar dados de sessão, cookies, autenticação e autorização, entre outros.

Comment: Muito obrigado Victor.