# Quais as vantagens de se utilizar os métodos HTTP corretos?

Tags: http

Eu já vi muita gente defendendo o uso dos métodos HTTP corretamente, ou seja, respeitando a semântica dos métodos [definidos na especificação](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5.1.1) ao fazer uma requisição. `GET` só deve ser utilizado para recuperar dados, e nunca para ações que causem efeitos colaterais. Os métodos `PUT` e `DELETE` muitas vezes devem ser utilizados no lugar do `POST`.

Porém é um fato óbvio que muito pouca gente na web faz isso, na prática `GET` e `POST` são utilizados quase que exclusivamente, por diversos motivos que não vêm ao caso.

Gostaria de saber quais as vantagens do uso correto, e as desvantagens do que é feito na prática, para além do dogma do "certo" e "errado" e da questão semântica.

Comment: Vou votar para fechar porque a pergunta só permite respostas vazias :P

Comment: Fechar é com `POST` ou `DELETE`?

Comment: A semântica correta deveria permitir ser `CLOSE` :)

Comment: Relacionado: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142652/what-is-the-usefulness-of-put-and-delete-http-request-methods

Comment: @Victor Então o correto para fechar seria `PUT`, certo? Duvido que este site faça isso (tentei testar agora, mas não consegui descobrir). E qual é o problema de não fazer? No fundo, essa é a minha pergunta.

Comment: Estou tentando bolar uma resposta para a sua pergunta, mas quanto mais eu pesquiso, mais confuso fico. Há meia hora atrás eu defendia o uso dos métodos DELETE, PUT e de outros acrescentados recentemente tais como o PATCH e os do WebDav. Porém, quanto mais pesquiso sobre isso, mais eu me convenço de que estes métodos parecem ser supérfluos e que no fundo não passa de um preciosismo semântico sem muito significado prático.

Comment: @Victor Pois é, eu acho algo parecido, mas espero que alguém me convença do contrário :)

Comment: Eu acho que a pergunta só fará o contrário :) Também gostaria de ver bons motivos para uso corrente, mas...

Comment: @QMechanic73 Esse link aí é POST vs GET apenas, essa é a parte fácil. O que o bfavaretto está pedindo é sobre PUT/DELETE vs POST.

Comment: Achei essa resposta do @Bruno bem interessante: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16930/14262

Comment: Pergunta da hora :)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Vamos começar vendo as nossas abordagens para fazer um CRUD em um servidor e forjar algumas URLs para analisar. A primeira abordagem (vamos chamá-la de **A**) é utilizar os verbos HTTP adequados:

> ```
> GET http://www.example.com/somepath/resource.txt
> PUT http://www.example.com/somepath/resource.txt
> DELETE http://www.example.com/somepath/resource.txt
> PATCH http://www.example.com/somepath/resource.txt
> ```

A segunda abordagem (**B**) é usar apenas GET e POST e colocar os verbos nas URLs:

> ```
> GET http://www.example.com/somepath/resource.txt
> POST http://www.example.com/somepath/resource.txt/put
> POST http://www.example.com/somepath/resource.txt/delete
> POST http://www.example.com/somepath/resource.txt/patch
> ```

A terceira abordagem (**C**) é usar apenas GET e POST e definir campos de formulário no POST:

> ```
> GET http://www.example.com/somepath/resource.txt
>
> POST http://www.example.com/somepath/resource.txt
> action=put&content=...
>
> POST http://www.example.com/somepath/resource.txt
> action=delete
>
> POST http://www.example.com/somepath/resource.txt
> action=patch&data=...
> ```

---

Agora, vamos analisar as vantagens da abordagem **A** sobre as abordagens **B** e **C**:

**Vantagem 1:** Todas as ações têm a mesma URL e portanto todas elas claramente se referem a ações sobre um mesmo recurso. Se você subiu um recurso com o PUT, é esperado obter o mesmo recurso ao utilizar GET, alterá-lo com PATCH e destruí-lo com DELETE.

**Vantagem 2:** O PUT, o DELETE e o PATCH são idempotentes, mas o POST não é. As requisições POST não são cacheadas e em geral não podem ser repetidas, diferentemente do que ocorre com o PUT, o DELETE e o PATCH. Mas no caso em que o POST representa um PUT, DELETE ou PATCH disfarçado, elas deveriam ser cacheáveis e repetíveis, mas o navegador ou algum outro agente não vai saber disso, pois a semântica está dentro da aplicação e não no protocolo.

**Vantagem 3:** Os métodos PUT, DELETE e PATCH são mais simples puros do que quando encapsulados em POSTs disfarçadas. Com o PUT, por exemplo, a sua requisição conterá como corpo apenas o recurso que você deseja utilizar para realizar o upload e nada mais. Se você utilizar o POST no lugar, terá que se virar com múltiplos campos de formulário e talvez com regras especiais para o `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

**Vantagem 4:** O verbo HTTP utilizado deixa claro qual que é a ação que está sendo efetuada sobre o recurso e portanto o comportamento esperado é bem definido. Se estivermos limitados apenas ao GET e ao POST, a URL terá que ser alterada (abordagem **B**) ou você será obrigado a definir campos de formulário customizados (abordagem **C**). O ideal é que as URLs fossem preservadas e nenhum campo customizado fosse necessário.

**Vantagem 5:** O processamento do POST não é tão bem definido do ponto de vista do HTTP, pois a sua semântica depende inteiramente da aplicação, diferentemente do que acontece com o PUT, o DELETE e o PATCH. No HTTP, o POST denota apenas o envio de dados ao servidor, mas não diz nada sobre como estes dados serão processados.

No entanto as vantagens da abordagem **A** acabam aí. Agora que eu já as enumerei, vou apresentar as desvantagens e também desconstruir as vantagens apresentadas:

---

**Desvantagem 6:** Navegadores suportam apenas formulários com as actions POST e GET. Isso costuma ser motivo suficiente para forçar os desenvolvedores a abandonar o PUT e o DELETE, uma vez que os navegadores não conseguirão utilizá-los de forma efetiva e simples.

É possível utilizar os demais métodos via AJAX. Mas em formulários não dá [porque tal como explicado por Ian Hickson](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=10671#c16) o PUT não faria sentido porque não tem sentido fazer upload do conteúdo de um formulário, e sim apenas upload de recursos, coisa que formulários não são. O DELETE não faz sentido em formulários porque o método DELETE não tem corpo e o formulário representa o corpo da requisição. [(link que usei para achar essa informação)](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/211790/43532).

Como resultado, [na especificação do HTML5 apenas o POST e o GET são aceitos como métodos de submissão de formulários](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#form-submission):

> The `method` and `formmethod` content attributes are [enumerated attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#enumerated-attribute) with the following keywords and states:
>
> - The keyword `get`, mapping to the state **GET**, indicating the HTTP GET method.
> - The keyword `post`, mapping to the state **POST**, indicating the HTTP POST method.
>
> The *invalid value default* for these attributes is the [GET](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fs-method-get) state. The *missing value default* for the [`method`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fs-method) attribute is also the [GET](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fs-method-get) state. (There is no *missing value default* for the [`formmethod`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fs-formmethod) attribute.)

Traduzindo isso para o português:

> Os conteúdo dos atributos `method` e `formmethod` são [atributos enumerados](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#enumerated-attribute) com as seguintes palavras-chaves e estados:
>
> - A palavra-chave `get`, mapeando para o estado **GET**, indicando o método HTTP GET.
> - A palavra-chave `post`, mapeando para o estado **POST**, indicando o método HTTP POST.
>
> O *valor assumido quando inválido* para estes atributos é o estado [GET](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fs-method-get). O *valor assumido quando omitido* para o atributo [`method`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fs-method) também é o estado [GET](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fs-method-get). (Não há *valor assumido quando omitido* para o atributo [`formmethod`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fs-formmethod).)

Assim, [os navegadores só aceitam POST e GET em formulários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16827/132).

Por outro lado, é verdade que [talvez isso mude no futuro](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-form-http-extensions-20140529/#http-put-form), mas por enquanto é assim ([link que usei para achar esta informação](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/264735/43532)).

Quando/se os navegadores permitirem o uso de PUT e DELETE em formulários, o uso do botão voltar dos navegadores poderá valer-se da idempotência ou cacheabilidade destes métodos e mostrar mensagens mais amigáveis para o usuário do que as que ocorrem quando tenta-se voltar para uma página que é resultado de um POST. Essa é uma pequena possível futura vantagem semântica da abordagem **A**, mas realmente é algo perfeitamente dispensável na prática e embora possa resolver o problema da desvantagem 6 depois que os navegadores antigos que não a implementem caírem em desuso, não resolve o problema da desvantagem 7 (ver abaixo) e nem dá nenhuma outra vantagem significativa para a abordagem **A**. Quando/se isso for implementado, poderemos usar PUT e DELETE em APIs, mas o que de fato estamos ganhando na prática com isso?

<sup><sup>Nota: Obrigado ao [Marcelo Bonifazio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/14262/marcelo-bonifazio) pelo [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/49322/quais-as-vantagens-de-se-utilizar-os-m%c3%a9todos-http-corretos/49330#comment99810_49322) que me permitiu encontrar a [resposta do Bruno Augusto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16930/14262).</sup></sup>

**Desconstruindo a vantagem 1:**

A vantagem 1 não se aplica apenas a abordagem **A**, mas também para a abordagem **C**, uma vez que a URL não muda vez que os parâmetros de formulário não fazem parte da URL.

Além disso, na prática esta vantagem não é significativa sobre a abordagem **B**. E daí que neste caso a URL não é idêntica? Qual é o problema disso na prática? O que ocorre é que na prática a difereça das URLs não representa nenhum tipo de desvantagem.

**Desconstruindo a vantagem 2:**

E daí que o POST não é idempotente? Se você tiver controle do programa do servidor e do programa cliente poderá implementar qualquer mecanismo de cache ou repetição que quiser. Se o seu programa cliente é o navegador web, então ele não poderia fazer cache ou repetição da requisição de qualquer jeito, pois devido a desvantagem 6 acima, ele não poderá usar PUT, DELETE ou PATCH por qualquer meio que não seja o AJAX, e requisições AJAX não são cacheáveis e nem repetíveis (e nem deveriam ser).

Portanto, se você está usando o navegador, a idempotência destes métodos não significa nada. Se por outro lado o seu programa cliente for customizado, então você pode decidir cachear ou repetir requisições como bem entender, mesmo que se trate de um POST (apenas faça isso de forma inteligente, cacheando apenas o que você souber que é cacheável e repetindo apenas o que souber que é repetível). Ou então, o seu programa cliente customizado pode ignorar completamente as questões de cache e repetição de requisição uma vez que isso raramente irá atender a alguma necessidade prática e real no caso do PUT, DELETE ou PATCH.

**Desconstruindo a vantagem 3:**

E daí que o uso do PUT, DELETE ou PATCH disfarçados como POST é um pouco mais complexo do que eles puros? Esta complexidade extra na prática é desprezível e trata-se de um problema resolvido e superado, e não é nada que um pouco de código no servidor não resolva. Muitas vezes tal código até já se encontra implementado dentro de frameworks, [tal como ocorre com o Ruby-on-Rails](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16821/por-que-os-navegadores-n%c3%a3o-implementam-os-protocolos-put-e-delete-do-http/16930#comment31794_16930).

**Desvantagem 7:**

Na abordagem **B** somos obrigados a modificar a URL para especificar qual é a ação desejada. Novamente, tal como explicado quando desconstruí a vantagem 1, isto não costuma ser um problema real na prática. Para a abordagem **C**, a necessidade de se adicionar parâmetros de formulários também não costuma consistir em desvantagem real.

No entanto, na abordagem **A** a ação é especificada no método HTTP. E além do GET, temos o PUT, o DELETE e recentemente o PATCH e só. Podemos usar o [WebDAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV) para obter mais alguns métodos (tais como COPY, MOVE, LOCK e PROPFIND, entre outros), mas ficamos limitados a um conjunto pré-definidos de verbos HTTP, caso contrário somos forçados a usar o POST... Ou será que não?

Imagine que de acordo com a abordagem **C** tenhamos URLs com POST assim:

> ```
> POST http://www.example.com/somepath/resource.txt
> action=banana
>
> POST http://www.example.com/somepath/resource.txt
> action=crazy
>
> POST http://www.example.com/somepath/resource.txt
> action=lol&type=huebr
>
> POST http://www.example.com/somepath/resource.txt
> action=hellokitty
> ```

Até aqui tudo bem. Se usarmos a abordagem **B** ao invés disso, tudo bem também:

> ```
> POST http://www.example.com/somepath/resource.txt/banana
> POST http://www.example.com/somepath/resource.txt/crazy
> POST http://www.example.com/somepath/resource.txt/lol&type=huebr
> POST http://www.example.com/somepath/resource.txt/hellokitty
> ```

Agora vamos tentar usar a abordagem **A** nestes casos:

> ```
> BANANA http://www.example.com/somepath/resource.txt
> CRAZY http://www.example.com/somepath/resource.txt
> LOLHUEBR http://www.example.com/somepath/resource.txt
> HELLOKITTY http://www.example.com/somepath/resource.txt
> ```

Isso é ridículo! Ok que inventar métodos HTTP customizados dá algum trabalho e é algo bem incomum e nada recomendável de fazer sem ter pensado muito bem a respeito, mas não é impossível (tanto que é o que o ocorre no caso do WebDAV). Isso é factível especialmente se você tiver controle sobre a implementação tanto do cliente quanto do servidor. Entretanto, isso demonstra que os verbos HTTP pré-definidos PUT, DELETE e PATCH, ou mesmo importados de extensões HTTP bem conhecidas como os do WebDAV só farão sentido para um conjunto significativamente pequeno e simples de ações que você possa realizar. Para as demais ações, o comportamento e a semântica são completamente alheios a especificação HTTP ou a de qualquer extensão HTTP bem conhecida e ficam completamente por conta da aplicação, e portanto acaba sendo melhor, mais simples, mais fácil e mais prático se ater ao POST nestes casos ao invés de inventar novos métodos HTTP malucos.

Ainda podemos tentar salvar a abordagem **A** com algo assim:

> ```
> PUT http://www.example.com/somepath/resource.txt/banana
> PUT http://www.example.com/somepath/resource.txt/crazy
> PUT http://www.example.com/somepath/resource.txt/lol&type=huebr
> PUT http://www.example.com/somepath/resource.txt/hellokitty
> ```

Ou simplesmente isso:

> ```
> PUT http://www.example.com/somepath/resource.txt     (Usa PUT como se fosse BANANA)
> PATCH http://www.example.com/somepath/resource.txt   (Usa PATCH como se fosse CRAZY)
> COPY http://www.example.com/somepath/resource.txt    (Usa COPY do WebDAV para LOL HUEBR)
> MOVE http://www.example.com/somepath/resource.txt    (Usa MOVE do WebDAV para Hello Kitty)
> ```

Mas isso daí não nos trás nenhum benefício, pois acaba por jogar fora as vantagens da abordagem **A** sem se livrar de nenhuma das desvantagens. Nesta bizarrice apenas estamos usando métodos arbitrários e semanticamente incorretos por teimosia para não usar o POST.

Alguém pode querer afirmar que as duas formas acima são espantalhos que construi da abordagem **A**. Talvez esta afirmação até esteja correta, mas isso não muda o fato de que em muitas circunstâncias os métodos HTTP pré-definidos são insuficientes e daí a melhor solução acaba sendo usar o bom e velho POST. Além disso, caso a ação a ser realizada não tenha relação com o que propõem o PUT, o DELETE, o PATCH ou alguma extensão particular do HTTP (exemplo: WebDAV). então não vejo outra hipótese para tentar (fracassadamente) salvar a abordagem **A** que não seja inventar métodos HTTP novos ou forçar o uso dos métodos HTTP existentes mesmo que inadequados.

**Desconstruindo as vantagens 4 e 5:**

Devido a desvantagem 7, na abordagem **A**, o significado da ação especificada no verbo HTTP só se aplica a alguns casos particulares, mas quando esbarrarmos em situações aonde nenhum verbo HTTP pré-definido se aplica, então iremos ou forçar o uso de um método HTTP semanticamente inadequado ou então teremos que inventar verbos HTTP novos e em ambas as situações a semântica bem-especificada vai para o beleléu, e acaba sendo mais fácil usar o POST (ou seja, abandonar a abordagem **A**).

Além disso, não há muita vantagem na prática ter a semântica da ação bem especificada no verbo HTTP, exceto no caso do GET (e de métodos HTTP mais básicos como HEAD, OPTIONS e TRACE), mas estes são idênticos em todas as abordagens. O que a semântica de se usar PUT e DELETE ao invés de um POST equivalente trás de bom e palpável na prática?

---

**Conclusão:** As vantagens que a abordagem **A** apresenta não são significativas e úteis na prática, mas as suas desvantagens em alguns casos são preocupantes e atrapalham o desenvolvimento de aplicações. Por outro lado as desvantagens das abordagens **B** e **C** são de pouca relevância.

É verdade que se você estiver desenvolvendo uma API que será utilizada por um programa cliente customizado ou então acessada via AJAX, você poderá usar o PUT e o DELETE sem problemas e então evitará a desvantagem 6 da abordagem **A**. Entretanto também é verdade que você igualmente poderá utilizar o POST sem problemas e portanto a abordagem **A** não oferecerá qualquer vantagem prática sobre as abordagens **B** e **C**.

Como resultado, concluo que é mais simples e mais fácil se ater aos velhos GET e POST e usar qualquer uma das abordagens **B** ou **C**. Me convenci de que não há qualquer vantagem prática de se usar PUT, DELETE ou PATCH e que eles são apenas um preciosismo semântico, sendo que na verdade estes métodos são supérfluos podendo todos eles serem representados pelo POST.

Também é verdade que as abordagens podem ser combinadas. Nada impede de você ter uma API aonde algumas partes sigam a abordagem **A**, outras sigam a abordagem **B** e outras sigam a abordagem **C**, e até consigo pensar em alguns motivos para fazer isso (obviamente que isso só se aplica aos métodos que não são baseados em GET). Entretanto, isso irá criar uma API que terá um estilo frankenstein (mas isso provavelmente não é nenhum problema na prática) e as partes da API que usarem a abordagem **A** não terão muitas vantagens técnicas práticas por fazê-lo, de forma que essa escolha ocorrerá por mero capricho ou preciosismo do desenvolvedor, ou talvez por algum tipo de imposição artificial vinda de alguma especificação, ferramenta ou framework. Também é perfeitamente possível disponibilizar funcionalidades de forma redundante, aonde uma mesma funcionalidade pode estar disponível por meio de diferentes abordagens (o que seria um frankenstein polimórfico):

> ```
> PUT http://www.example.com/somepath/resource.txt
> POST http://www.example.com/somepath/resource.txt/put
> ```

Na minha experiência pessoal, quando eu estava projetando alguma API através da abordagem **A** e esbarrava na desvantagem 7, mesmo que sem perceber isso, eu acaba ou usando o POST (ou seja, abandonando a abordagem **A** pura e criando um frankenstein) ou então eu acabava forçando o uso de um método HTTP inadequado, e acredito que o mesmo ocorra com muitos outros desenvolvedores que tentem seguir a abordagem **A**.

Mas não há nada que salve a abordagem **A**? Bem, se você estiver em um cenário aonde a idempotência dos métodos PUT e DELETE (ou algum outro) lhe for útil, isso pode fazer a diferença. Ou seja, se você estiver em um cenário aonde a desvantagem 6 não se aplica (especialmente se/quando os navegadores os aceitarem em formulários, ou então você está usando um cliente customizado) e a vantagem 2 sobrevive a tentativa de desconstrução (ou seja, a cacheabilidade e repetibilidade existem na prática estando bem implementadas, trazendo benefícios reais para o seu caso e não são ou não podem ou não devem ser aplicadas seletivamente a POSTs), então você terá um ponto positivo relativamente forte a favor de usar os métodos PUT e DELETE. Entretanto na maioria dos casos que acontecem na prática, essas situações não se aplicam ou não fazem qualquer diferença, e eu consigo inclusive visualizar casos aonde o programador projeta a API e se esquece de que PUT e DELETE são idempotentes e acaba por usá-los inadequadamente (e portanto deveria usar POST mesmo).

E agora que terminei a minha resposta, que comece o <strike>flamewar</strike> **debate** nos comentários. :)

Comment: Vou começar com o 'flamewar': isso não é uma resposta. Isso é um artigo de conclusão de curso, :)

Comment: Verdade, devias escrever um artigo sobre o assunto :)

Comment: Obrigado por toda pesquisa e pela resposta abrangente! Andei pensando também, e em certos serviços RESTful (nem todos) faz sentido o uso semanticamente correto. De tudo que você disse, a questão do cache me pareceu o motivo mais forte para decidir. Claro, dá para contornar como você mencionou no "desconstruindo 2", mas poder aproveitar algo pronto nesse caso seria vantajoso. Eu usaria se os forms HTML (e talvez também âncoras) permitissem escolher os outros métodos.

Comment: @bfavaretto Acrescentei um parágrafo no final para mostrar aonde a abordagem A pode se salvar.

Comment: Gostaria apenas de dizer que no caso colocado existe a especificação que recomenda a abordagem A do @Victor...  mas como sabemos muitos são aqueles que gostam de não seguir as especificações alegando vantagens. na minha opinião uma especificação existe por algum motivo. Grande resposta em tamanho e conteúdo! quando cheguei ao fim estava cansado. fora de brincadeiras...parabéns.

Comment: @chambelix Há casos aonde a especificação é furada. E além disso, eu foquei mais no caso do programador que vai inventar a API REST dele usando os métodos que achar melhor. Quando tratar-se de uma API já definida, normalmente deve-se apenas obedecer o que ela pede. Me parece que o principal motivo que faz o PUT e o DELETE existir são questões semânticas e idempotência.

Comment: @Victor concordo 100% com o teu comentário e considero que a realidade nos leva muitas vezes a furar a especificação... eu enquanto profissional faço-o. No entanto tenho de admitir que uma especificação deve ser respeitada. Dou exemplo: se eu desenvolver fora da especificação obriga-me a documentar tudo para futuro, se seguir a especificação a minha documentação não precisa de ser tão exaustiva... este é um exemplo entre outros.

Comment: Por algum motivo bizarro, esta resposta não estava marcada como aceita até hoje. Peço desculpas, erro corrigido :)

Comment: É cansativo de ler, mas muito interessando e didático.

Comment: Deveria gerar uma wiki sobre a resposta.

Comment: Desculpem minha ignorância, mas o que você quer dizer com **cacheabilidade** ?

Comment: @DiegoFelipe Significa algo que pode ser cacheado. Ou seja, trata-se de um tipo de informação que pode ser armazenada em uma memória temporária sem ser buscada em sua real fonte. Para uma informação ser cacheável, deve ser uma informação que ou nunca muda ou que não gera nenhum problema se puder ser vista desatualizada de vez em quando. Por exemplo, mapas de uma região geográfica são cacheáveis, pois sofrem alterações muito lentamente e usar uma versão desatualizada por alguns dias não é problemático. Já dados de transações bancárias não são cacheáveis e devem estar sempre atuais.

Comment: @VictorStafusa obrigado pelo esclarecimento, nem percebi que tinha a ver com **cache**, por isso a dúvida.

Comment: simplesmente fantástica a resposta e os detalhes, se for verdade tudo isso(rsrs), realmente não faz sentido usar esses métodos do http, pois o POST pode ser a melhor opção atualmente

Comment: Parabéns pela resposta. Estamos querendo atingir o nível 3 do modelo de maturidade de Richardson para os nossos serviços. E este post, me fez questionar a real necessidade de fazer essa tarefa. De todo modo, irei pesquisar mais a respeito para tentar ter uma opinião formada!

Comment: Recomendo separar por capítulos kkkkkk. Brincadeiras a parte, Parabéns por todo o trabalho de pesquisa e por esta resposta.