# Dúvida sobre comportamento $.post e $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net

Sempre fui acostumado a usar `$.ajax()` para todas as minhas requisições do tipo, e isto funciona perfeitamente. Um exemplo que inclusive está ocorrendo agora é o seguinte:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "XmlTree.aspx/GetChildren",
        data: {id : teste},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {

            if (callback) {
                callback(msg);
            }
        },
        error: function (msg) {
            if (callback){
                callback(msg);
            }
        }
    });
```

Chamando assim, ele cai no método que eu pretendia. Tudo funciona certo, conforme a imagem abaixo mostra:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, dei uma lida sobre o `$.post` e sua sintaxe me pareceu ***muito mais simples***, e eu decidi testar, da seguinte maneira:

```
$.post( "XmlTree.aspx/GetChildren", { id : "S1000" } );
```

o problema é que, independentemente dos meus parâmetros, usando `$.post` ele sempre cai no Page_Load, como mostra a imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou ciente da existência dessa pergunta: [Quais as vantagens de se utilizar os métodos HTTP corretos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/49322/quais-as-vantagens-de-se-utilizar-os-m%C3%A9todos-http-corretos/49330#49330).

Mas ainda assim não consegui entender o motivo desse comportamento. O `$.post` também não deveria cair diretamente no meu método `GetChildren`?

Comment: Usando a função `$.post` você precisa serializar os dados por conta própria. Tente requisitar o endereço e passar uma string como parâmetro -> `$.post( "XmlTree.aspx/GetChildren", JSON.stringify({id : "S1000" }) );`

Comment: @LINQ ele aceita um [`PlainObject`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) também.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Mas provavelmente ele vai enviar como formdata e o backend não vai desserializar isso

Comment: Artur, isso é WebForms?

Comment: @LINQ tentei passar os dados como uma string, mas mesmo assim caiu no Load :/. Sim, é WebForms

Comment: Você precisaria ver como estão as duas requisições, tem algo que diferencia as duas e faz o backend tratá-las de forma diferente.

Comment: @LINQ fui analisar o `payload` na aba Network do devtools do chrome, e apesar de ambos estarem iguais, o `$.post` consta como FormData, mesmo eu colocando ele em forma de string, e o `$.ajax` consta como string.

Comment: @ArturoTemplário [Aparentemente você não tem opção](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2845471/4190610), $.post vai sempre mandar um formdata.

Comment: @LINQ entendi, então presumo que as situações em que o `$.post` pode ser utilizado corretamente estão respondidos na pergunta que citei

Answer (score 1):

O método `post` aceita 4 parâmetros, [de acordo com a documentação](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/#jQuery-post-url-data-success-dataType).

`jQuery.post( url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] )`

Assim, pode fazer a mesma chamada *setando* o tipo de dado enviado como json assim:

```
$.post('XmlTree.aspx/GetChildren', { id : 'S1000' }, 
    function (msg) { ... }, 
    'json'
);
```