# Boas Praticas em APIS Rest Full com PHP e Doctrine ORM 2

Tags: php, api, doctrine, asp.net-web-api, slim

Atualmente temos um sistema que usa o Doctrine ORM2, temos nossas Entidades, e temas nossas DAOS, dentro de nossas classes DAOS temos vários métodos que usamos para fazer consultas, Alterar, Inserir e Deletar Dados no Banco de Dados.

Criamos alguns prefixos para essas operações:

> - slt => select
> - lst => listar
> - get => buscar geralmente por um ID específico
> - alt => alterar
> - ins => inserir
> - del => delete

Sendo assim um nome para um método na classe **UsuariosDAO** que irá inserir um novo usuário ou buscar um especifico no sistema seria:

> insUsuario ou getUsuario

Até ai tudo bem, o problema é que estou criando uma api e queria usar esses métodos DAOS já prontos para fazer várias operações no banco, estou usando o **Slim Framework** para me ajudar na criação da api, e eu queria usar as DAOS da seguinte forma:

> https://api.com/usuarios/getUsuario/5
>
> https://api.com/usuarios/getUsuario?id=5

Onde:

- Onde usuarios => UsuariosDAO
- Onde getUsuario => método da classe UsuariosDAO

Mas eu pesquisei e li que usar nomes de métodos em uma api não é boa pratica, e tenho classes aqui que chegam a ter mais de 50 métodos diferentes, e eu não sei o que fazer pois queria usar esses métodos já prontos, como eu poderia fazer isso usando os meus métodos que já estão prontos nas DAOS ?

Comment: [Quais as vantagens de se utilizar os métodos HTTP corretos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49322/91), https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/api-design e http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/restquicktips.html

Comment: A ideia do REST é representar um recurso por isso usar verbos ou ações nos nomes das uri não é recomendado. Não ficou claro na pergunta você usa algum mecanismo que bate no controler e casa com o nome do método e executa ele? O nome dos métodos dos seus DAOs não precisa ir para a uri.

Comment: Ao fazer uma requisição usando esta url por exemplo: https://api.com/usuarios/getUsuario/5, eu trato o nome "usuarios", transformo em UsuariosDAO, instancio essa classe DAO usando ReflectionClass e verifico se o método getUsuario existe nessa classe, caso exista passo os argumentos para o método e retorno o resultado da consulta.

Comment: Você disse que o nome dos métodos das DAOs não precisam ir para url, mas como vou saber, ou gerenciar o que o usuário realmente quer ?

Comment: Uma rota vai apontar para o método desejado o verbo também pode ajudar nesse caso. Não é necessário externalizar todos métodos de uma classe para a API, só retorne o que for útil.

Comment: Entendi então toda uma rota deve referenciar apenas um método especifico ? E a medida que a API for crescendo eu crio as rotas e também os métodos ?

Comment: Não é um rota por método, o usuário não precisa conhecer a sua estrutura de classe. O ponto importante é definir o **proposito** da API, quem vai usar ela? quais funcionalidades/servições são interessantes para meus consumidores? quais recursos vou externalizar? Esqueci de comentar no, no site do restapitutorial tem um pdf para donwload recomendo a leitura das seções `Querying, Filtering and Pagination` e `Resource Naming Anti-Patterns`

Comment: Entendi, vou da uma lida aqui e vou seguir o que você falou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usei o manual que o amigo **rray** me indicou, e me aprofundei bastante na teoria o que me fez ter um entendimento maior de como funciona essa tecnologia para porque aplicar os melhores métodos de programação para a resolução de meus problema.